# jQuery closest() and find()

Tags: jquery, find, closest

I'm trying to figure out a way to only select one calculator at a time by using jQuery transverse functions closest() and find(). At its current state when pressing a button it will use both calculators. I need it to only use one calculator at a time. Need some help. Is the html laid out correctly? I know that with many tutorials on DOM Traversing they use ul and li, should I here?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="calcWrap">
        <h2>Calculator One</h2>
        <div action="" class="calculator">
                <input type="text" class="answer" value="" disabled="disabled"/><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 1" value="1">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 2" value="2">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 3" value="3">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol /" value="/">/</button <br>
                <button type="button" class="number 4" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 5" value="5">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 6" value="6" >6</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol *" value="*">*</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 7" value="7">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 8" value="8">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 9" value="9">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol -" value="-">-</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 0" value="0" >0</button>
                <button type="button" class="number ." value=".">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="C" value="C">C</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol +" value="+">+</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="equals =">=</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h2>Calculator One</h2>
        <div action="" class="calculator">
                <input type="text" class="answer" value="" disabled="disabled"/><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 1" value="1">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 2" value="2">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 3" value="3">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol /" value="/">/</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 4" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 5" value="5">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 6" value="6" >6</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol *" value="*">*</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 7" value="7">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 8" value="8">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 9" value="9">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol -" value="-">-</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 0" value="0" >0</button>
                <button type="button" class="number ." value=".">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="C" value="C">C</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol +" value="+">+</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="equals =">=</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
 body {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: lightgray;
}

html {
font-size: 1vw;
}

h2 {
font-size: 2rem;
color: white;
}

.calcWrap {
width: 43rem;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding: 2rem;
margin-top: 10rem;
border: 0.3rem solid black;
border-radius: 1.5rem;
background-color: #3E7CB1;
}

li {
float: left;
}

.answer {
width: 43rem;
height: 12rem;
background-color: lightgray;
font-size: 4rem;
text-align: right;
font-weight: lighter;
padding: 2rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number {
width: 10.5rem;
height: 10.5rem;
background-color: #DBD5B5;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
color: black;
font-size: 4rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
}

.symbol {
width: 10.5rem;
height: 10.5rem;
background-color: #FCAB10;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
color: black;
font-size: 4rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
} 

.C {
width: 10.5rem;
height: 10.5rem;
background-color: #F8333C;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
color: #E4FDE1;
font-size: 4rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
} 

.equals {
width: 43rem;
height: 10rem;
background-color: #44AF69;
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 6rem;
color: white;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

**scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var numberOne;
var numberTwo;
var operator;
var $result = $(".answer");

function reset() {
    numberOne = null;
    numberTwo = null;
    operator = null;
    $result.val("");
}

reset();

$(".number").click(function() {
    var clickDigit = $(this).text();
    var currentVal = $result.val();
    var newVal;
    if(currentVal === "") {
        newVal = clickDigit;
    } else {
        newVal = currentVal + clickDigit;
    }
    $result.val(newVal);
});

$(".symbol").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    numberOne = parseFloat($result.val());
    $result.val("");
});

$(".equals").click(function() {

    var total;

    numberTwo = parseFloat($result.val());

    if(operator === "+") {
        total = numberOne + numberTwo;
    } 
    else if (operator === "-") {
        total = numberOne - numberTwo;
    }
    else if (operator === "/") {
        total = numberOne / numberTwo;
    }
    else if (operator === "*") {
        total = numberOne * numberTwo;
    }

    $result.val(total);

});

$(".C").click(function() {
    reset();
});

$(this).closest(button).find(".answer");

});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest(button).find(".answer");` is this what you are referring?what is this context? also what is button? .answer should be child of button and this should be parent of button

Comment: from what i can tell you code to in question is not in any event

Answer (score 1):

Your code does need a lot of cleanup but seeing the scope you have set on `$result`, adding the following line to the `$('.number')` `click` event handler, your issue is partially resolved:

```
$result = $(this).closest('.calculator').find('.answer');
```

**(See the demo below)**

As long as you start by clicking a `.number` it works. A slightly better approach would be to add this line to every event handler. The demo is not an attempt to solve your problem but simply to demonstrate what approach to take to solve it.

I have removed the following line (by commenting it).

```
$(this).closest(button).find(".answer");
```

This is because it does not do what you want it to do, `this` at that point refers to `window` and there's nothing you're doing with the resulting collection even if the scope was correct; `this` in your case would only point to a `DOM` element within an event handler.

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOne;
    var numberTwo;
    var operator;
    var $result = $(".answer");

    function reset() {
        numberOne = null;
        numberTwo = null;
        operator = null;
        $result.val("");
    }

    reset();

    $(".number").click(function() {
        $result = $(this).closest('.calculator').find('.answer'); //Change 1: ADDED
        var clickDigit = $(this).text();
        var currentVal = $result.val();
        var newVal;
        if (currentVal === "") {
            newVal = clickDigit;
        } else {
            newVal = currentVal + clickDigit;
        }
        $result.val(newVal);
    });

    $(".symbol").click(function() {
        operator = $(this).text();
        numberOne = parseFloat($result.val());
        $result.val("");
    });

    $(".equals").click(function() {

        var total;

        numberTwo = parseFloat($result.val());

        if (operator === "+") {
            total = numberOne + numberTwo;
        } else if (operator === "-") {
            total = numberOne - numberTwo;
        } else if (operator === "/") {
            total = numberOne / numberTwo;
        } else if (operator === "*") {
            total = numberOne * numberTwo;
        }

        $result.val(total);

    });

    $(".C").click(function() {
        reset();
    });
  
    //$(this).closest(button).find(".answer"); //Change 2: REMOVED

});
```

```css
body {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: lightgray;
}

html {
font-size: 1vw;
}

h2 {
font-size: 2rem;
color: white;
}

.calcWrap {
width: 43rem;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding: 2rem;
margin-top: 10rem;
border: 0.3rem solid black;
border-radius: 1.5rem;
background-color: #3E7CB1;
}

li {
float: left;
}

.answer {
width: 43rem;
height: 12rem;
background-color: lightgray;
font-size: 4rem;
text-align: right;
font-weight: lighter;
padding: 2rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number {
width: 10.5rem;
height: 10.5rem;
background-color: #DBD5B5;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
color: black;
font-size: 4rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
}

.symbol {
width: 10.5rem;
height: 10.5rem;
background-color: #FCAB10;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
color: black;
font-size: 4rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
} 

.C {
width: 10.5rem;
height: 10.5rem;
background-color: #F8333C;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
color: #E4FDE1;
font-size: 4rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
} 

.equals {
width: 43rem;
height: 10rem;
background-color: #44AF69;
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 6rem;
color: white;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="calcWrap">
        <h2>Calculator One</h2>
        <div action="" class="calculator">
                <input type="text" class="answer" value="" disabled="disabled"/><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 1" value="1">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 2" value="2">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 3" value="3">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol /" value="/">/</button <br>
                <button type="button" class="number 4" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 5" value="5">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 6" value="6" >6</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol *" value="*">*</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 7" value="7">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 8" value="8">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 9" value="9">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol -" value="-">-</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 0" value="0" >0</button>
                <button type="button" class="number ." value=".">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="C" value="C">C</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol +" value="+">+</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="equals =">=</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h2>Calculator Two</h2>
        <div action="" class="calculator">
                <input type="text" class="answer" value="" disabled="disabled"/><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 1" value="1">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 2" value="2">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 3" value="3">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol /" value="/">/</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 4" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 5" value="5">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 6" value="6" >6</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol *" value="*">*</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 7" value="7">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 8" value="8">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="number 9" value="9">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol -" value="-">-</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="number 0" value="0" >0</button>
                <button type="button" class="number ." value=".">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="C" value="C">C</button>
                <button type="button" class="symbol +" value="+">+</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="equals =">=</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Was alerted to this question I posted back in 2016 and though I'd post what my solution was. Link to live page [here](http://calculator.scharvey.com/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var numberOne; // setting global variable for first number(s) submitted
    var numberTwo; // setting global variable for second number(s) submitted
    var operator; // global for operator buttons
    var result; // setting global display as blank because we don't know which calculator to use yet


        $('.number').click(function() {
            result = $(this).closest('.calculator').find('.answer'); // click event using .closest() to travel up DOM to locate nearest '.calculator', then used '.find' to output to '.answer' input
            var clickDigit = $(this).text();
            var newVal; 
            var currentVal = result.val();

            if(currentVal === '') { // if no value newVal will equal clickDigit
                newVal = clickDigit;
            } else {
                newVal = currentVal + clickDigit; // adds more than one number to screen
            }

            result.val(newVal); // outputing to screen

        });

        $('.symbol').click(function() {
            operator = $(this).text(); // storing operator variable to be used 
            numberOne = parseInt(result.val()); // dealing with numbers, returns an integer
            result.val('');
        });

        $('.equals').click(function() {
            
            numberTwo = parseInt(result.val()); // dealing with numbers, returns an integer

            var $total; // local variable 

            // takes from local variable operator and checks the value
            if(operator === '+') {
                total = parseInt(numberOne + numberTwo); // adding together // dealing with numbers, returns an integer
            } 
            else if (operator === '-') {
                total = parseInt(numberOne - numberTwo); // subtracting one from another // dealing with numbers, returns an integer
            }
            else if (operator === '/') {
                total = parseInt(numberOne / numberTwo); // dividing one from another // dealing with numbers, returns an integer
            }
            else if (operator === '*') {
                total = parseInt(numberOne * numberTwo); // multiplying together // dealing with numbers, returns an integer
            }

            result.val(total); // outputting equals .clicked event

        });

        $('.C').click(function() { // clearing all values to null or empty
            numberOne = [];
            numberTwo = [];
            operator = [];
            result.val('');
        });

});
```

```css
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

html {
    font-size: 1vw;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}

.calcWrap {
    width: 43rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid black;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #3E7CB1;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.answer {
    width: 43rem;
    height: 12rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pressed {
    background-color: blue;
}

/*.workSpace {
    width: 43rem;
    height: 4rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}*/

.number {
    width: 10.5rem;
    height: 10.5rem;
    background-color: #DBD5B5;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    color: black;
    font-size: 4rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.symbol {
    width: 10.5rem;
    height: 10.5rem;
    background-color: #FCAB10;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    color: black;
    font-size: 4rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
} 

.C {
    width: 10.5rem;
    height: 10.5rem;
    background-color: #F8333C;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    color: #E4FDE1;
    font-size: 4rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
} 

.equals {
    width: 43rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: #44AF69;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator App</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'>
</head>

<body>
        <div class='calcWrap'>
            <h2>Calculator One</h2>
            <div class='calculator'>
                    <input type='text' class='answer' value='' disabled='disabled'/><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 1' value='1'>1</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 2' value='2'>2</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 3' value='3'>3</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol /' value='/'>/</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 4' value='4'>4</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 5' value='5'>5</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 6' value='6' >6</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol *' value='*'>*</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 7' value='7'>7</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 8' value='8'>8</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 9' value='9'>9</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol -' value='-'>-</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 0' value='0' >0</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number .' value='.'>.</button>
                    <button type='button' class='C' value='C'>C</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol +' value='+'>+</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='equals ='>=</button>
            </div>

            <h2>Calculator Two</h2>

            <div class='calculator'>
                    <input type='text' class='answer' value='' disabled='disabled'/><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 1' value='1'>1</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 2' value='2'>2</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 3' value='3'>3</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol /' value='/'>/</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 4' value='4'>4</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 5' value='5'>5</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 6' value='6' >6</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol *' value='*'>*</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 7' value='7'>7</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 8' value='8'>8</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number 9' value='9'>9</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol -' value='-'>-</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='number 0' value='0' >0</button>
                    <button type='button' class='number .' value='.'>.</button>
                    <button type='button' class='C' value='C'>C</button>
                    <button type='button' class='symbol +' value='+'>+</button><br>
                    <button type='button' class='equals ='>=</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to use ul, li.

Refer this example to understand the dom traverse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //console.log($('.fourth').parent().attr('class'));

        //console.log($('.fourth').closest('.second').html());

        //console.log($('#d1').find('span').html());

        //console.log($('#d1').next('p').html());
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first">
      <div class="second">
        <div class="third">
          <div class="fourth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="d1">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div id="d2">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="d3">
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

remove the commented console.log() one by one and understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

Use `first()` to get the first or `eq()` to get the element at postion x[0,length-1]

```
$(this).closest(button).find(".answer").first();
```